# Comanswer duplicates Superuser answers

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, meta

I was just doing some Google searches to find out how to selectively always trust certain certificates on intranet pages using Google Chrome on a Mac.  I came across this [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/104049/the-sites-security-certificate-is-not-trusted-on-every-ssl-page).  Another link in the Google Search pointed to [this comanswer page](http://www.comanswer.com/question/the-site-s-security-certificate-is-not-trusted-on-every-ssl-page), which exactly duplicates the superuser.com content!

Anyway, just wanted to call this to attention & I don't really have a specific question (apologies & please close this if it's inappropriate for meta.su).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contents of Super User & other Stack Exchange network are licensed as [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [Attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

> So let me clarify what we mean by attribution. If you republish this content, we require that you:
>
> - Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> - Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
> - Show the author names for every question and answer
>   Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

The site you mention follows each of these rules, and hence is giving attribution back - and hence as of now nothing needs to be done.

Answer (score -2):

Same thing happened with a question that I submitted to Super User (duplicated as a YouTube video with attribution, and an actor reading it, which was very odd). I guess it's a way to generate free content.